# What percentage of wizards are born from wizard families?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

I was looking at a [comment here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7363/98), and realized that I don't know what percentage of wizards are born to wizard families, and what are born to muggle families? Anyone out there know the answer?

Comment: I had actually considered a similar (at least strongly related) question the other day...

Comment: And for clarification, do you want half-wizard families? I think that should be a third category, pure, half, muggle-born.

Comment: @Kevin: You won't find any complains from me on that one. It sounds fine to include the third category.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In *Chamber of Secrets*, Ron says,

> “Most wizards these days are half-blood anyway. If we hadn’t married Muggles we'd've died out.” (CoS – Chapter 7)

Sirius Black tells Harry in *Order of the Phoenix* that most “pure-blood” wizarding families have both Muggleborns (Ted Tonks) and half-bloods (Nymphadora Tonks) in their family tree, but don't want to acknowledge it. He also notes that there are so few "pureblood" families left that they are, by that point, all interrelated.

> “The pure-blood families are all interrelated. If you’re only going to let your sons and daughters marry pure-bloods your choice is very limited; there are hardly any of us left.” (Sirius Black – OotP – Chapter 6)

[On her website](http://web.archive.org/web/20110713111552/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=100), J.K. Rowling says:

> Don’t forget that, as Sirius revealed in *Order of the Phoenix*, none of these families is really ‘pure’ – in other words, they merely cross Muggles and Squibs off the family tree and pretend that they didn't exist. But yes, the number of families claiming to be pure is diminishing. By refusing to marry Muggles or Muggle-borns, they are finding it increasingly difficult to perpetuate themselves. This subject is touched upon in *Half-Blood Prince*.

[She also says](http://web.archive.org/web/20100210133643/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=58):

> The expressions ‘pure-blood’, ‘half-blood’ and ‘Muggle-born’ have been coined by people to whom these distinctions matter, and express their originators' prejudices. As far as somebody like Lucius Malfoy is concerned, for instance, a Muggle-born is as ‘bad’ as a Muggle. Therefore Harry would be considered only ‘half’ wizard, because of his mother’s grandparents.
>
> If you think this is far-fetched, look at some of the real charts the Nazis used to show what constituted ‘Aryan’ or ‘Jewish’ blood. I saw one in the Holocaust Museum in Washington when I had already devised the ‘pure-blood’, ‘half-blood’ and ‘Muggle-born’ definitions, and was chilled to see that the Nazis used precisely the same warped logic as the Death Eaters. A single Jewish grandparent 'polluted’ the blood, according to their propaganda.

It appears that “pure-blood” families are becoming less prevalent; half-bloods comprise the majority of the Wizarding population; Muggleborns are less prevalent than half-bloods, but are perhaps a slightly higher population than pure-bloods. If I were to throw out some numbers, I might guess 15% pure-blood, 65% half-blood, and 20% Muggleborn. Something along those lines.

It’s interesting that Muggleborns are descended from Squibs, who are pure-blood wizards who lack the dominant magic gene (but who apparently still carry it as a recessive trait).

Comment: `It's interesting that Muggleborns are descended from Squibs` If this is true it might indicate that there are far more squibs born than magics(?) even in wizard families. Otherwise, why would the original pure-bloods (if there was such a thing) have been unable to perpetuate themselves unless they were excluding the squibs from marrying those who had the talent?

Comment: @Xantec I believe someone mentioned in the books that squibs were encouraged to integrate into muggle civilization.  The inability to perpetuate themselves assumes that there would be more pure-bloods marrying muggles or muggle-borns than other pure-bloods, which seems fair, especially once the trend has started and the number of pure-bloods decreases.

Comment: @Xantec - Kevin is correct. Information on Squibs is available at J.K. Rowling's website: http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=19 (I hope it's okay to post a link in a comment . . .)

Comment: Yes, links in comments are fairly common and, as far as I have heard, not discouraged.  You can give them text too: [text](link)

Comment: Does a wizard marrying a muggle constitute a "wizard family", regardless of whether or not the wizard is pure-blood, half-blood, or muggle-born?

Comment: @Beofett - That's a great question. I would say that if a witch or wizard partnered up with a Muggle, but did not have children from that union, then, no, they would not be a wizarding family. I also don't see a family with non-magical parents and only one magical child (like Lily Evans' family) as a wizarding family proper. But if a witch or wizard and a Muggle went on to produce magical children, then I would consider them a wizarding family. This is just my own conjecture, though. Others may have different ideas! :)

Answer (score 5):

The corollary is that wizards born to two Muggles must be incredibly rare, because there are so many Muggles and so few wizards. Given 40 or so wizardly children of the same age in the UK out of around [644453 births per year](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=UK%20births%20by%20year) and the only known fact that two Muggle-borns were in the same year as Harry gives us something like 1 per 320000 births.

This implies that around 375 Muggle-borns are born world-wide per year, if we assume the distribution of the Muggle-born wizards is uniform across the planet. If there were pure-bred families in other places then I think it's plausible that a population of wizards with 1 or fewer Muggles among their immediate 32 ancestors could be maintained forever if those individuals/families all wanted to do so.

Answer (score 4):

I dont think the exact percentage was ever stated. But it's undertone that it is fairly low.

It we take Harry's cohort as a representative sample, the [Known Muggle-borns List](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Muggle-born#Known_Muggle-borns) (which is fairly short) only gives [Hermione](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hermione_Granger) and [Justin Finch-Fletchley](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Justin_Finch-Fletchley).

J. K. Rowling made [draft list of students in Harry Potter's year](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_Me) :

> [...] the year group is to compose of 40 students, 10 belonging to each house [...]

It gives 38/40 = 95%. But we don't know the lineage of all students, and there is at least 2 other student that are listed as Muggle-born in this list, but later works contradicted it.

**So, we could safely guess that a fairly high percentage of wizards are born from wizard families, probably in the vicinity of 90%, plus or less 5%.**

Answer (score 0):

I would probably say around 20% Pure Bloods are still around, Draco Malfoy is a pure-blood and some other Wizards and witches , was it Salazar slytherin , Godric griffindor and the other two are pure bloods? And they have decendants  such as Ginny who opened the chamber of secrets although she isn't pure blood... Probably most wizards are Half-Bloods such as , Ginny , Ron , Fred , George , Percy and so and so, there mother isn't actually a witch or it's their dad that isn't a wizard , either way their family was married into the wizarding world, I think around 50% Of wizards these days are Half Bloods. Now we come to Muggle born wizards , now I'm gonna use the other name for them and I appologise if I offend you with it... Mud-bloods. Hermione granger is a Mud-Blood and so is Colin but other than that they don't come into the story much , Also I forgot Luna is a halfblood

Comment: 20% pure-bloods + 50% half-bloods + 30%... with no blood?