# Work after completing Hogwarts

Tags: harry-potter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What jobs can wizards and witches do within the world of magic?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13148/what-jobs-can-wizards-and-witches-do-within-the-world-of-magic)

What do witches and wizards do after they complete their education of witchcraft and wizardry? Do they return back to the muggle world? If yes, they would be considered as uneducated since they don't have any degree with them and they can't tell about magic.
And, if they stay in the magic world what do they do for a living? Since a large number of students becomes wizards/witches every year, what jobs do they get?

Comment: Duplicate. We already had a Q covering work after Hogwarts.

Comment: See also [What jobs can wizards and witches do within the world of magic?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13148) and [Is there an estimate of how many people work for Ministry of Magic?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7446)

Answer (score 6):

As per the linked [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7445/are-there-non-squib-wizards-witches-who-work-100-in-muggle-world), there are almost no witches/wizards holding jobs in Muggle world aside from "official liaison" to government leads (e.g. Kingsley or Merlin).

As per another [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/is-there-an-estimate-of-how-many-people-work-for-ministry-of-magic), a large portion of adult witches/wizards works for Ministry of Magic (the best estimate based on JKR's broken math is ~1/3 of entire wizarding population). With 1/3 being in Hogwarts, the other 1/3 works assorted Wizarding jobs (running shops, teaching, crime, Gringotts, pro sports, entertainment, etc...)