# Was Sir Cadogan a wizard?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles

This question is simple: Was sir Cadogan a wizard or a muggle?

**If he was a wizard:**

Why is he wearing armor and riding a horse? he can use protective charms and ride a broomstick.

> A moment later, a short, squat knight in a suit of armour had clanked into the picture after his pony.

**If he was a muggle:**

What is he doing in a Hogwarts portrait?

Also: does this mean that muggles can move in wizard portraits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there non-squib wizards/witches who work 100% in muggle world?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7445/98028) - CF [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/183330/98028) which largely details Cadogan's life; he was a indeed a wizard, who took on a Muggle job as some others did in this era.

Comment: I've voted to close as a dupe. The alternate question is wider (and hence *includes* Sir Cadogan) and the supplied answer entirely answers this question.