# Hogwarts Teaching Books

Tags: harry-potter

I've recently watched all of the *Harry Potter* movies. I was really excited by them.

But I had one question - which has nearly nothing to do with the concept: What kinds of books and lessons would be used at Hogwarts?

I mean sure they learn about magic but they are also taught about magical creatures, e.g.:

- Hippogryphs by Hagrid, and
- Werewolves by Severus Snape

They also learn how to make potions etc.

I would also like to see some sort of illustrations, other than what is shown in the movies. For example the book "*The Resurrectionist*" contains beautifully illustrated pictures of anatomy of magical creatures such as Mermaids, Sphinxes etc.

**Are there similar (text-book style) books in the Harry Potter universe?**

Comment: I can't get your question, sorry. Please try to improve it for clarification.

Comment: Indeed. Are you just asking http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/does-hogwarts-teach-non-magical-classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Book lists are one thing that Harry Potter Wikia is good at.

1. Overall list of books:

   https://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_books

   That list - especially relevant to your question - contains a gazillion Magical Creatures books.
2. Specifically Hogwarts textbooks (except for Year 7 that we don't know about since Harry didn't attend):

   https://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Supply_list

#### First year

- *The Standard Book of Spells (Grade 1)* by Miranda Goshawk
- *A History of Magic* by Bathilda Bagshot
- *Magical Theory* by Adalbert Waffling
- *A Beginner's Guide to Transfiguration* by Emeric Switch
- *One Thousand Magical Herbs and Fungi* by Phyllida Spore
- *Magical Drafts and Potions* by Arsenius Jigger
- *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* by Newt Scamander
- *The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection* by Quentin Trimble

#### Second year

- *The Standard Book of Spells (Grade 2)* by Miranda Goshawk
- *Break with a Banshee* by Gilderoy Lockhart
- *Gadding with Ghouls* by Gilderoy Lockhart
- *Holidays with Hags* by Gilderoy Lockhart
- *Travels with Trolls* by Gilderoy Lockhart
- *Voyages with Vampires* by Gilderoy Lockhart
- *Wanderings with Werewolves* by Gilderoy Lockhart
- *Year with the Yeti* by Gilderoy Lockhart

#### Third year

- *The Standard Book of Spells (Grade 3)* by Miranda Goshawk
- *Unfogging the Future* by Cassandra Vablatsky (if attending Divination)
- *Intermediate Transfiguration* by Emeric Switch
- *The Monster Book of Monsters* (if attending Care of Magical Creatures)
- *Numerology and Grammatica* (if attending Arithmancy)
- *Home Life and Social Habits of British Muggles* by Wilhelm Wigworthy (if attending Muggle Studies)
- *Spellman's Syllabary* (if attending Study of Ancient Runes)
- *The Essential Defence Against the Dark Arts* by Arsenius Jigger

#### Fourth year

- _Dress Robes (only for special occasions that will occur through the year)
- *The Standard Book of Spells (Grade 4)* by Miranda Goshawk
- *The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection*

#### Fifth year

- *The Standard Book of Spells (Grade 5)* by Miranda Goshawk
- *Defensive Magical Theory* by Wilbert Slinkhard

#### Sixth year

- *The Standard Book of Spells (Grade 6)* by Miranda Goshawk
- *Advanced Potion-Making* by Libatius Borage
- *Confronting the Faceless*
- *A Guide to Advanced Transfiguration* by Emeric Switch
- *Advanced Rune Translation*
- *Flesh-Eating Trees of the World*

Comment: Lockhart's collected works and arugably any book for DADA is not necessarily for that year, but rather what the then current DADA teacher, who never lasts more than a year, prescribes. As opposed to _The Standard Book of Spells_, which seems like such a standard work that students might as well buy the entire series right away.

Answer (score 7):

Students at Hogwarts study a variety of different subjects, each with it's own textbook(s). Several of them were named in the books and described to some degree. The following are compulsory subjects:

- **Potions**: Where students learn how to create various magical potions.
- **Transfiguration**: Changing the shape of objects.
- **Defense Against the Dark Arts**: How to defend oneself against dark magic.
- **Charms**: How to use incantations and bewitchment.
- **Astronomy**: Pretty obvious.
- **Herbology**: The use and care of magical plants.
- **History of Magic**: The history of the magical world and its wizards and witches.
- **Flying**: How to fly using a broom.

Hogwarts students are also required to take two more elective subjects from the following list:

- **Arithmancy**: Magical properties of numbers.
- **Muggle Studies**: The non-magical world and its culture.
- **Divination**: Foretelling the future.
- **Study of Ancient Runes**: Studying ancient runic scripts.
- **Care of Magical Creatures**: The study and care of magical creatures such as hippogriphs and dragons.

Incidentally, JK Rowling has written and published the actual textbook used for Care of Magical Creatures. A book entitled ["Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them), which is available for sale with proceeds going to charity.

Comment: +1 on *Fantastic Beasts*, I think this is along the lines of what the OP is looking for!

Comment: Isn't Advanced Potion Making also available as an in-universe textbook?

Comment: @ZenLogic - Not that I know of, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Harry Potter and his fellow Hogwarts students use a number of books during their school years. They usually received a list of books to buy at *Flourish and Blotts*, the bookstore in Diagon Alley, before the next year began.

I can't give an exhaustive list, but I'll name some highlights.

A standard work is *The Standard Book of Spells* series, written by Miranda Goshawk. It consists of seven books, one for each year at Hogwarts. Another standard textbook was *Advanced Potion-Making* by Libatius Borage, for their Potions class.

Due to the *unfortunate* circumstances surrounding the teacher for Defence Against the Dark Arts, they had to buy a new book for that almost every year. These included *The Essential Defence Against the Dark Arts*, *Confronting the Faceless*, *The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection*, but also the collected works of Gilderoy Lockhart in the year that he taught the class.

When Hagrid taught Care of Magical Creatures, he used *The Monster Book of Monsters* by Edwardus Lima. It is an aggressive textbook that attacks anyone who attempts to open it. The only way to get it to open is to stroke its spine.