# Do Hogwarts students learn the core subjects?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I understand that students at Hogwarts learn about magic, but what about the core subjects such as Math, English, History, and Science? If they do not wish to pursue a career in magic, they need to know these core subjects!

Comment: I would tag this with science too, but if I did it would not be right for the tag. English is not a tag.

Comment: The question isn't about math, or history, or science, or art or whatever. It's about curriculum.

Comment: Not a very close duplicate IMO.  But I guess I can post my answer over there.  (Sigh.)

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/186087/5930

Comment: @HarryJohnston and OP: If this question were reworded to say "Why do Hogwarts students not need to learn non-magical subjects?" I would vote to reopen it.

Comment: @Kevin, that's how I interpreted it.  But I'll leave it to the OP to decide whether to rephrase.

Comment: Even if they pursue a career in magic, thy still want to have taken an English class or two. If they want to write and publish a paper about their new magic spell theory or something, they will still (probably) need to use language. Unless they use some kind of Sorting-Hat-type artificial intelligence device for writing. But it's always best if the author is able to write about their own processes and conclusions.