# Does Xavier's School for Gifted Youngsters teach normal school subjects?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men

The main purpose of Xavier's School for Gifted Youngsters (and later the Jean Grey School for Higher Learning) seems to be to teach mutants to use their powers. Does the school also teach "normal" school subjects, like mathematics, history, language arts, or science? Would a mutant at this school ever learn stuff like algebra or physics?

I'm interested in the main Marvel comics line (Earth-616, or whatever it calls itself these days), although other universes or media would be interesting supplementary information.

Comment: Oh my,  when Jean Grey took over [they had Gambit as a sex-ed teacher](https://i.imgur.com/aM0JJyl.jpg) :'D _(link is safe for work)_

Comment: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-8xzB0v9ou4w/U37q9P-2E9I/AAAAAAAAJFY/tDmWRts-3C4/s1600/X-Men+-+Wolverine's+class+syllabus.JPG

Comment: Actually that does bring the question: does Jean Grey's School for higher learning count?

Comment: @Jenayah I'm not familiar with the distinction. Is it pretty much the same facility? Like, they weren't operating at the same time, and Jean Grey's school is designed to succeed Xavier's?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. Wolverine, Beast, Kitty and co rebuilt the thing to host a new school, named after Jean Grey (the Professor wasn't dead, though), basically to start anew, with better hopes for mutant integration through control of their powe... Yeah you guessed it by the end of first issue the school is attacked and it's mayhem. So, hey, pretty much basically the same. (save for toilets seats on fire - yes, that's a thing)

Comment: @Jenayah I've revised the question to say that the Jean Grey school is okay, although it would be helpful to have an answer that covers both eras of management. Might have to ask a new question about the toilet seats on fire!

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7436/4918 "Does Hogwarts teach non magical classes?"

Comment: @Jenayah it depends. It kinda died out for a while, but then it came back with a fire beneath it. Sadly, it died out again. But it came back! But it was never the same after that...

Comment: Note, of course, that the classes we see are going to be dictated by the needs of the story. A random class might be used for an exchange of comments amongst students, but the specific class would rarely be of significance, and might not even be mentioned. And, of course, most standard high school or college classes aren't going to substitute for action in a story, whereas powers training is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it was (at least occasionally) implied that they do. In X-Men 168 (am I showing my age here?) a temporarily demoted (from X-Men to New Mutans) Kitty Pryde angrily wonders how she "can do any work without the proper lesson programs" for her computer. Context (e.g. that she is in her room, not in the danger room) suggests that this is homework rather than some sort of training for her powers.

[image]

In the same issue she has dancing lessons together with Illyana (Magik), so "normal" stuff is at least approved of by Xavier.

Comment: "am I showing my age here?" Well, you weren't until you asked, since it's entirely feasible you might have read old comics despite being young... =)

Comment: I remember that gag! I don't mind showing my age. — Who drew that issue?

Answer (score 32):

**Movies: Yes.**

The first three X-Men movies show scenes of children getting taught regular subjects. These include Prof. X [teaching a (presumably) English Lit class](http://www.killermovies.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-20053-the-once-and-future-king-connection.html) about *The Once and Future King*, and in the first film Prof. X [doling out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UI8QIBTxVmo) (what I think is) physics homework. There is also a scene of Storm teaching a class in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cL_zqTuWMj8). You can't hear what's being said as it's been over-dubbed with music, but can see what is probably the word "Romance" on the board so again, maybe an English Lit lesson.

Comment: While this is a good answer from the movies, I'm looking for an answer for the comics, so I won't be accepting this answer in its current form.

Comment: I said that they would be useful as "supplementary information". If you'd rather, I can remove that part from the question.

Answer (score 20):

In *X-Men* (1963) #7, Professor X seems to indicate that the school does cover subjects beyond training mutant powers, in that the original 5 students have earned diplomas indicating they've successfully completed a standard prep school curriculum:

[image: X-Men diplomas, from *X-Men) (1963) #7, page 2]

While it's possible that he means they completed such a curriculum prior to coming to Xavier's, it wouldn't make sense for him to be providing a diploma covering such if that were the case.

Answer (score 4):

### YES

The original school has long since branched off from Xavier’s original class. Xavier initially created “Xavier’s School for Gifted Youngsters” as a front to hide his super-team of mutants.

However, as Xavier took in more youngsters, he understood the kids needed to be educated as well. Consequently, his original students became teachers, along with others affiliated with the X-Men family.

[Some examples of people who taught academic coursework over the years:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xavier_Institute_students_and_staff) Also, [another similar source:](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Xavier_Institute_student_body)

**Xavier’s School Teachers:**

- Cyclops/Scott Summers: Has been headmaster as well as a former geometry/leadership and tactics teacher.
- White Queen/Emma Frost: Also been headmistress and mentor of the Hellions at the Massachusetts Academy; as well as a former ethics teacher.
- Karma/Xi’an Coy Manh was the former secretary to the headmaster, a former librarian, a former French teacher
- Colossus/Piotr Rasputin was art teacher.
- Magma/Amara Aquilla was geology teacher.
- Mirage/Danielle Moonstar was American history teacher
- Beast/Hank McCoy was science teacher.
- Nightcrawler/Kurt Wagner was a drama teacher.
- Northstar/Jean-Paul Beaubier was a former business class and flight teacher.
- Phoenix/Jean Grey-Summers was a headmistress.
- Shadowcat/Kitty Pryde was a computer science teacher.
- Wolverine/James Howlett was a PE instructor.
- Angel/Warren Worthington III was a flight instructor.

**Jean Grey School for Higher Learning staff members*:**

- Cannonball/Sam Guthrie was a junior staff member and flight professor
- Warren Worthington III/Angel is a graduate assistant and recruiter
- Chamber/Jono Starsmore is a junior staff member and professor of psychology and professional standards
- Hank McCoy/Beast was the vice-principal and professor of science and philosophy
- Cypher/Doug Ramsey was another junior staff member and professor of foreign languages and communications
- Doop is adjunct staff, the Introduction to Religion professor, and receptionist
- Deathlok is also adjunct staff as well as security
- Husk/Paige Guthrie was a former literature professor and current guidance counselor
- Angelica Jones/Firestar is a senior staff member and professor of physics and chemistry.
- Gambit/Remy LeBeau was a senior staff member and former sex-ed professor; he left to join X-Factor.
- Frenzy/Joanna Cargill is a junior staff member and gym teacher.
- Karma/Xi’an Coy Manh is a junior staff member and librarian.
- Iceman/Bobby Drake is a senior staff member and math professor.
- Lockheed was a professor of Alien Races; he left to teach at - -

**Cyclops’s New Xavier School**

- Marvel Girl/Rachel Summers is a professor of psychic defense and space survival
- Rogue/Anna Marie was a senior staff member and linguistics professor.
- Shadowcat/Kitty Pryde was a professor for time-displaced students who also left to go to Cyclops’s school.
- Storm/Ororo Munroe is the current headmistress and professor of multicultural studies.
- Wolverine/James Howlett was the former headmaster and professor of history & PE
- Warbird/Ava’Dara Naganandini is a junior staff member, school protector, and arts and painting professor.

Comment: I came to this question to specifically list off some teachers & subjects, but you beat me to the punch by about 15 minutes. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

No, the school does not teach normal subjects.

In *X-Men* #1 in the 1960s, Iceman is reported to be 16 years old and it's implied that he is the "baby" of the group, i.e. the youngest. All of the (original) team were of an age to have completed a normal High School education.

The purpose of the school is explicitly stated by Professor X in that 1st issue:

> I realised the human race is not yet ready to accept
>    those with extra powers! So I decided to build a haven...
>    a school for X-Men. Here we stay, unsuspected by normal
>    humans, as we learn to use our powers for the benefit
>    of mankind...

The "school" is a fake, designed to give the appearance to outsiders of being an ordinary college for High School graduates, but this is only camouflage.

It in fact acts as a haven for the team members, where they're trained to use their superpowers to best effect. It's also their headquarters. But Professor X never claims to be qualified to teach ordinary courses, and Jack Kirby never shows the team in an actual classroom.

Comment: Jack Kirby may not have, by several other artists and writers did in later runs

Comment: Even so, this answer adds to the conversation since it shows the original intention of Kirby. Have an upvote.

Answer (score -2):

At least starting in 2004 it did get turned into a real high school that also taught mutants how to use their powers. I'm not sure what it is currently, as I haven't kept up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).